# Is this jQuery code right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, input

```
function like(){
    $('#likeo').html('<div style = "align:center"><img src = "images/loader.gif"></div></br>').show();
    var pid = <?php echo $post; ?>;
    $.post('include/like.php',{pids:pid} , function(data){
        $('#likeo').html(data).show();
    })
}
```

Is this jquery code right??. I tried everything and failed to get it working. this function gets executed by this code :

```
<input type='button'
 value='Like'
 name='like'
 id='inputl'
 class='buttonl'
 style='width: 46.4%; margin-top: 10px;'
 onclick = 'javascript:like();'>
```

It is a Ajax based post like system. the variable $ post is the post id to be liked. Basically, what it should do is :

- First show the loader while doing the work
- get the POST ID to send to the PHP code
- using jquery, send the post ID to like.php with variable pid . And on completion of the task, Display the reply of php instead of the loader.

**Thanks guys, Finally got it working**

Comment: Considering how badly formatted it is, and also the fact that you haven't told us what the code is supposed to do, this is a very difficult question to answer.

Comment: Nop, it doesn't look right...

Comment: ALright, I will write what it is for..

Comment: The `onclick` code passes a parameter to the function, but the function doesn't take any arguments. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Why do people always like to put `javascript:` inside `onclick`?!

Comment: BTW, there's no need for `javascript:` in `onXXX` attributes.

Comment: I guess there is a typo too. There is no element with id "likeo". So you should fix this line. `$('#likeo').html`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Because they don't understand the different between putting JS in `onclick` and `href`.

Comment: @Barmar - IMO they should really read more on how `onclick` works... btw they should avoid inline code anyway.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 99% of the people posting questions on SO have no clue what they're doing, so what do you expect?

Comment: Is there just one post on the page?

Comment: Barmar, you can view just one page at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, its wrong, because the function `like` does not take any argument in your original code, even though you are passing an argument in the function call.

```
function like(id){
    $('#likeo').html('<div style = "align:center"><img src = "images/loader.gif"></div></br>').show();
    var pid = id;
    $.post(
        'include/like.php',
        {pids: pid},
        function(data){
            $('#likeo').html(data).show();
        }
    )
}



<input
   type = 'button'
   value = 'Like'
   name = 'like'
   id = 'inputl'
   class = 'buttonl'
   style = 'width:46.4%;margin-top:10px;'
   onclick = 'like(<?php echo $post; ?>);'
>
```

Comment: I tried it, it doesnt work. And this is freaking me out. I have another code for commenting which is basically a edit if this like function. That works, I can comment in the page but cannot like. And I swear to god, it is the same code:

Comment: which part is not working? Does the function execute? `console.log` the `id` inside the like function

Comment: No, its not the semicolon.

Comment: try console.log() inside your function. See if you are getting the correct `id` and `data` inside your `post` request's success callback.

Comment: No, the function doesnt execute. And I didnt understand. What console.log.. I am a beginner, I dont know how to use console.log and i hate my life.

Comment: Relax... and read up on how to use console.log in google. It will serve you well in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Make the like function receive a parameter and stop passing it in by echoing $post.

```
function like(pid){
    $('#likeo').html('<div style = "align:center"><img src = "images/loader.gif"></div></br>').show();
    $.post('include/like.php',{pids:pid} , function(data){
        $('#likeo').html(data).show();
    })
}
```

Your onclick should look like this:

```
onclick="like(<?php echo $post; ?>);"
```